# Rate of exchange at a specific date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was creating the query presented below that returns the amount of payment/reserve for a claim file. The idea is that the conversion into local currency for reserve is made on the specified date exch_r."AtDate". However, the result returns the sum of amount in EUR, without suming the value in Lei.

Eg.: There are 3 reserves in EUR (200 eur; 9 EUR; 56 EUR) and one in Lei (110 LEI).

The result returned is 265 EUR * 4,8567 LEI = 1.287,0255 LEI, whitout adding the 110 Lei at the converted one.
My result shoud be 1.287,0255 + 110 LEI = 1.397,0255

```
select d."DAMFileNr", plata_lei
,coalesce(SUM(CASE WHEN d_rez."EID"='10' THEN d_rez."RDAM" ELSE 
           d_rez."RDAM"*exch_r."EXCValue" END),0) as rez_lei
from "DAM" as d
left join "DAMRez" as d_Rez on d."Index"=d_rez."DID"
left join lateral (
    select coalesce(sum(case when d_pay."EID"='10' then d_pay."PAYVal" else
                                d_pay."PAYVal"*exch_p."EXCValue" end),0) as plata_lei
    from "DAMPay" as d_pay
    LEFT JOIN "EXCValues" exch_p ON exch_p."AtDate"=d_pay."PAYDate" and exch_p."EID"=d_pay."EID"
    where d."Index" = d_pay."DID"
) d_pay on true
LEFT JOIN "EXCValues" exch_r ON exch_r."EID"=d_rez."EID"
where exch_r."AtDate"='2020-09-16' and d."DAMFileNr" like 'S/SC/05/2020'
group by d."DAMFileNr", plata_lei
order by d."DAMFileNr"
```

Could you please advise me how handle this issue?
Thanks

Comment: solved. I added a new condition: where (d_rez."EID"='10' or exch_r."AtDate"='2020-09-16') and d."DAMFileNr" like 'S/SC/05/2020'

Answer (score 0):

solved. I added a new condition: where (d_rez."EID"='10' or exch_r."AtDate"='2020-09-16') and d."DAMFileNr" like 'S/SC/05/2020'